# Use JavaScript object to create a new object for Google charts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to chart some data using Google's charting resources. It wants the data in a certain format such as:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004',  1000,      400],
    ['2005',  1170,      460],
    ['2006',  660,       1120],
    ['2007',  1030,      540]
]);
```

From what I can tell it wants the first series to contain the 'x' axis followed by any number of items representing the 'y' axis data points.

My data is coming from my back-end as follows:

[image: js object]

**Update (code to get chart data):**

```
function GetChartData(ni, dn, cn) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Dashboard?handler=QualityTests' + '&NodeId=' + ni + '&DomainName=' + dn + '&ComputerName=' + cn,
        success: function (json) {
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(json))
        }
    })
}
```

I want to plot just the `averageJitterInMs` for the 'x' axis and `dateTime` for the 'y' axis for now (I'll eventually use the rest of the data elsewhere on the page; possibly for other charts).

So is there an elegant way to pull just these values from my array (of potentially hundreds of array items) so it can feed the Google chart data requirements? By this I mean how do I get my two key/value pairs out of a JavaScript array so I can put it in the right format the charting resource wants (see the attached image)?

I've tried looping the array on the client side to pull out these two key/value pairs however the Google charting api is giving me an error:

> Not an array

Is this even necessary or can I somehow grab the key/value pairs programmatically to feed the `arrayToDataTable` method?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? What do you mean "pull these values from my array"? Actually you could just access any value from array via index like `myArray[0]`. Show us the code you are trying to use

Comment: Sure thing...I updated the question a bit as well. From what I can tell I need to have an array built in a completely different format from my source array. Have a look at the image showing the array of key/values and the expected format for the chart. I'll update the question to include how I'm trying this as well....give me a few.

Comment: Please do use a snippet so that we could reuse this to make an answer.

Comment: I hope this one is what you need https://codepen.io/CrUsH20/pen/GYMyBG?editors=1010 (check console for results)

Comment: could you post the code you're using to fetch the data ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak updated

Comment: That explains the err `Not an array` it's an object, you have to either loop through it's values `Object.values` or convert it to and array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build any array out of what you have. I've made a dummy data to show you how you could achieve what you want.

Here we have `array` with two options we want to pick (value1, value2).

Then we do a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over an array and assign the result to `resultArray`.

In map we do extract `value1` and `value2` from each element using [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Now we have an array of arrays.

```js
const array = [
 {
  value1: 'sadfsadf',
  value2: 'asdasdas',
  extra: 123123
 },
 {
  value1: 'sadfasfsadsadf',
  value2: 'asdasdas',
  extra: 123123123
 },
 {
  value1: 'eg',
  value2: 'asdssdas',
  extra: 124
 },
 {
  value1: 'sadfsadf',
  value2: 'sd',
  extra: 123123
 },
 {
  value1: 'sf',
  value2: 'sf',
  extra: 123123
 }
];

let resultArray = array.map(e => {
 let {value1, value2} = e;
 return [value1, value2];
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: This looks good. One question though, if my source data (one of the numeric values) is showing up as a string, can this be converted to a number? Given your example, imagine if '123123' was literally "123123" can you convert the type as you build the array?

Comment: In JS converting to a number is happening by prepending with `+`. I.e. `+'123' === 123`.

Comment: You can make values inside a map callback and then return them in array

Comment: Excellent. This worked! I had to also use `arr.unshift(["DateTime","AverageJitterInMs"])` to define my columns as well but I have a graph!! :)

Comment: @JasonShave-MSFT it's better to avoid `unshift` since it's much harder to operate than `push` for example. You could firstly create an array with initial columns then just push new values to it. Or, you could use array destructuring to `unshift`, however it should be more optimal as I know. Would be like `newArr = [newValue, ...oldArr]`